# Authenticating user login with PHP from Sqlite database

Tags: php, database, sqlite, pdo

My partner and I have been up for nearly 24 hours straight trying to figure this out, and I feel like it's something so simple that we shouldn't have an issue. We are trying to authenticate users using PHP from an sqlite database. We've seen countless posts and tutorials on how to do this with a mySQL database, but not sqlite3. The *one* we did find was on here and it did not work for us (and no, we are not just copying and pasting). So, can anyone tell us what is going wrong? We keep getting a server 500 error and its not validating at all. At first,the php would display on the page, but now we just get errors. 
In short -- we are trying to pull email address and password information from a sqlite database and validate it with php, so the user can login and see the member homepage.
PHP CODE:

```
    <?php
$dir = 'sqlite:db/Quizionality.db':
 $db = new PDO($dir) or die ("Unable to open");


 $email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];

 $email_address =($email_address);
 $password =($password);

 $email_address = intval($_POST["email_address"]);
 $password = intval($_POST["password"]);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email_address='$email_address' AND password='$password'";
 $sql .= "where email_address=? AND where password=?";

 $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindParam(1, $email_address);
 $stmt->bindParam(2, $password);
 $result = $stmt->execute($sql);

 while($column=$stmt->fetch())
 {
     echo $column["email_address"];
     echo $column["password"];
 };
  };


 if($email_address==1){
     echo "<h1>Logged In</h1>";
 };

?>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Quizonality</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/QuizonalityLogInForMembers.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav id="header_wrapper">
        <h1 id="logo"><a href="#"> QUIZONALITY</a></h1>
        <ul id="navigate">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Create</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>


<body>

<div id="main">


<h2 id="main_head"> Already Existing Members </h2>

<form id="loginform" name="myForm" method="post" action="login_for_mems.php">

<div>Username (Email):</div>
<input  id="username" type="text" name="username"  >


<div>Password:</div>
<input id="password" type="text" name="password" type="password">

<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" >
</br>

</div>

</form>




 <footer>
   <div id="footer_nav">
    <div id="footer_nav_wrapper">

     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Create</a></li>
     </ul>



  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

**PHP UPDATE w/ error reporting - this is what we have currently

```
    <?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$email = isset($_POST['username'])? $_POST['username'] : ''; 
$password = isset($_POST['password'])? $_POST['password'] : '';

$db = new PDO('sqlite:db/Quizionality.db');

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email_address = ? and password = ?');


$stmt->execute(array($email, $password));

if($stmt->rowCount())
    {
    echo "<h3>Logged In</h3>";
    }
  else
  {
    echo "<h3>Login Failed</h3>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Remove `WHERE email_address='$email_address' AND password='$password'";` parh form your query

Comment: `$dir = 'sqlite:db/Quizionality.db':` statement end with `semicolon` not `colon`

Comment: So many errors. for a start `1` is not a valid email address is it?

Comment: @steve , i was trying to set the value of 1 = to email address, although now looking at it, I see what I was trying to do, but I see why that doesnt work also

Comment: I keep getting a server error. Did I link it wrong?

Comment: Turn on error reporting, then you will get a usefull error message telling you whats wrong. However there is a bunch of nonsensical code here, for example ` $email_address =($email_address);` does absolutely nothing, `$email_address = intval($_POST["email_address"]);` will make `$email_address` an integer (`0`), which make no sense. The SQL has two identical where conditions, and the if clause is both illogical and does not consider the database result anyway

Comment: @Steve I'm not sure what's going on. It still says server error. I've updated my post with your changes. Should we just start over? Any tips on what we should do?

Comment: Ill write an answer for you - please 1st tell me how is the password saved in the database? Is it plain text? Or a hash? Also, what version of php are you using

Comment: Yes, they are stored in plain text for now. I didnt want to fool around with security until I get this done, and thank you! And I am using PHP5. Sorry for taking so long, I crashed. Ive had 0 sleep

Answer (score 0):

Please note your question suggests you are saving passwords as plain text in the DB - you **never** want to do that (use a hash instead) but the following code is designed to work with your exisiting database:

```
//get email and pass from POST - set to empty string if not set
$email = isset($_POST['username'])? $_POST['username'] : ''; //Your form html uses name="username" so thats the key we use here
$password = isset($_POST['password'])? $_POST['password'] : '';

//create PDO object with sqlite db
$db = new PDO('sqlite:db/Quizionality.db');

//prepare statement, with unnamed query parameters denoted by ? placeholder
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email_address = ? and password = ?');

//bind query parameters to placeholders and execute query
$stmt->execute(array($email, $password));

//rowCount does not work for SQLITE, however empty array is 'falsy', an array with content (in the case of a successfull login) is 'truthy', so:
if($stmt->fetchAll()){
    //do something now user is authenticated, eg set a SESSION value, redirect etc
    echo 'Logged In';
}
```

Again, i highly suggest you alter your database to use password hashes, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Also, a number of issues in your code are obvious sytax errors - any decent php IDE should be able to highlight those for you - so i recommend you use one. Netbeans is a great free one, PHPStorm is a (arguably better) paid one

Comment: Thank you so much! But I am still getting a server error??

Comment: Please turn on error reporting, then post what the full error is

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). Is it maybe permissions?

Comment: Thats not the full error message, how did you turn on error reporting

Comment: Put the error reporting code at the very top of the file

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: db in Quizionality/Login/login_for_mems.php on line 4 Fatal error: Call to a member function errorInfo() on a non-object in Quizionality/Login/login_for_mems.php on line 4

Comment: Remove the `  print_r($db->errorInfo());` line, that should not be at the top.

Comment: Ok, did that. Now when I click the log in button, the page is just blank. There are no error messsages though, which I guess is good

Comment: I have updated the PHP again. No matter what I put in, the screen shows Login failed, but will not show Logged in for a correct username and password

Comment: Oh, im sorry - `rowCount()` does not work with SELECT in SQLITE - i made an edit - use `fetchAll` instead

Comment: Ok, I changed it, but it still only says Login Failed. No errors or anything, but it will not say Logged In even when im using a username and password that is in the database